# Relation between outcomes of two random variables.

Tags: integration, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Even with the new Wolfram plugin for chatGPT, I'm struggling with the following question.

Suppose $X, Y \sim U(0, 2)$, i.e. both of them are independent and uniformly distributed. What would then be the probability that $\frac{A}{B} \in (1, 3)$?

This is what I've got so far and although I know the answer can't be right I simply don't see my mistake.

$\begin{align}&1 \leq \frac{A}{B} \leq 3, \newline &B\leq A\leq 3B,\end{align}$

whereby,

$\begin{align}&\int^2_{0}\left( \int^{3B}_{B}dA \right) dB, \newline &\int^2_{0}\left( 2B \right) dB, \newline &2^2-0^2 = 4\end{align}$,

would define the area that satisfies my condition. However, since the total parameter space is of size 4 this would imply that the required probability is 1 which doesn't make any sense.

Hopefully this question isn't too basic for this forum. Didn't know where else to turn.

Best,

Comment: Draw it on square $2 \times 2$

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicion is correct. When you sketch the event and sample space, it's clear that $\mathbb{P}\bigl(1<\frac{A}{B}<3\bigr) = \frac13$, as the triangle takes up one third of the square.

[image: Event in sample space.]

The problem with setting up the double integral the way you've suggested is that for each $B$ (vertical axis), the upper limit of integration for $A$ as a function of $B$ is piecewise:
$$
\begin{cases}
B < A < 3B, &\text{for } 0 < B < \tfrac23 \\
B < A < 2, &\text{for } \tfrac23 < B < 2 
\end{cases}
$$

The proper integral is then
$$
\mathbb{P}\bigl(1<\frac{A}{B}<3\bigr) 
= \frac14 \Biggl( 
\int_0^{\frac23} \int_B^{3B} \mathrm{d}A \, \mathrm{d}B 
+ \int_{\frac23}^2 \int_B^2 \mathrm{d}A \, \mathrm{d}B 
\Biggr) 
= \frac14 \biggl( \frac49 + \frac89 \biggr) 
= \frac13. 
$$

Of course, it's much cleaner to put $A$ on the outside of the integral, and for each $0 < A < 2$, consider $B$ such that $\frac13A < B < A$:
$$
\mathbb{P}\bigl(1<\frac{A}{B}<3\bigr) 
= \frac14 \Biggl( 
\int_0^2 \int_{\frac13 A}^A \mathrm{d}B \, \mathrm{d}A 
\Biggr) 
= \frac14 \cdot \frac43 
= \frac 13.
$$

---

Comment: Wow thank you very much for this explanation! Much appreciated.